# CFNetwork is crashed in iOS 7

Tags: ios, crash, cfnetwork

Application is crashed sometimes with such trace, I can't reproduce it.

```
Thread 16 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3b0f4b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CFNetwork                            0x308d9491 -[__NSCFLocalSessionTask setConnection:] + 718
2   CFNetwork                            0x30933c33 -[__NSCFLocalSessionBridge taskTerminating:] + 136
3   CFNetwork                            0x30932945 __64-[__NSCFLocalSessionBridge initWithConfiguration:session:queue:]_block_invoke + 46
4   CFNetwork                            0x30950b03 ___ZNK24ClassicConnectionSession28_connection_didFinishLoadingEP16_CFURLConnection_block_invoke + 96
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b5dcd1b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b5e3273 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 372
7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b5e306b _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b5e3ce1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b5e3f59 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 54
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b71edbf _pthread_wqthread + 296
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b71ec84 start_wqthread + 6
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? Not just the stack trace.

Comment: @Jonathan Date/Time:       2016-08-17T14:53:28Z
Launch Time:     2016-08-17T14:00:53Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x6000000c
Crashed Thread:  16

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: setBridge: